# Trying to create a method (and test) that counts all numbers,letters,and chars in a string and

Tags: java, junit

...and puts them into an array of size 4.

index 0 = how many uppercase letters

index 1 = how many lowercase letters

index 2 = how many numbers

index 3 = other

here is my code:

```
   package code;

public class PotentialQ {

    public int[] countAll(String input){

        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int count3 = 0;
        int count4 = 0;
        int [] fin = new int [4];

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){

            char ch = input.charAt(i);

            if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
                if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
                    count1++;
                }
                else
                    count2++;
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
                count3++;
            }
            else
                count4++;
        }
        fin[0] = count1;
        fin[1] = count2;
        fin[2] = count3;
        fin[3] = count4;

        return fin;

    }

}
```

here is my test:

```
 package tests;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class PotentialQTests {

        int [] arr = {1,3,3,1};

        @Test public void test1() {testCode("Baaa123!", arr);}

        private void testCode(String input, int [] expected) {
            code.PotentialQ pq = new code.PotentialQ();
            int [] actual = pq.countAll(input);
            assertTrue("It was " +actual, expected == actual);
        }
    }
```

my error is a bunch letters and numbers.
what is the problem with my code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
assertTrue("It was " +actual, expected == actual);
```

You are calling == on primitive arrays, I'd recommend updating this to

```
assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
```

The description "It was " +actual isn't going to tell you much - just the ref for the array. To see the contents you could do

```
assertArrayEquals("It was " + Arrays.toString(actual), expected, actual);
```